# MySQL MATCH doesn't work with two characters?

Tags: mysql, match

I have a table called 'business' with the following sample data:

```
Street - 150 N Michigan Ave.
City - Chicago
State - IL
Zip - 60601
```

When I run a query like

```
SELECT business.* 
    WHERE MATCH(business.Street, business.City, business.State, business.Zip)
                AGAINST('*150*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
-- IT WORKS


SELECT business.* 
    WHERE MATCH(business.Street, business.City, business.State, business.Zip)
                AGAINST('*Chicago*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
-- IT WORKS


SELECT business.* 
    WHERE MATCH(business.Street, business.City, business.State, business.Zip)
                AGAINST('*60601*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
-- IT WORKS


SELECT business.* 
    WHERE MATCH(business.Street, business.City, business.State, business.Zip)
                AGAINST('*IL*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
-- DOESNT WORK!!
```

So what's wrong with the last query?

Any ideas?

Comment: Although I am not sure why you have a problem I would not suggest for a production environment to use this type of query if your table might become large.

Comment: why is that? How would you suggest I do this? I need do match if users search for '150 N Michigan' or 'Michigan n 150 IL' etc etc. Basically kinda like a google search :P

Answer (score 7):

Update the `ft_min_word_len` variable in the `my.cnf` MySQL configuration file:

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=N
```

Note that afterwards indexes must be rebuilt.

Comment: I can not find `ft_min_word_len` in the `my.cnf` file, why? *(it should be noted that I use Xampp)*

Comment: You have to add it.

Answer (score 4):

Fulltext search stop some common word, but it is disable using this steps.

1: open my.ini file in MYSQL configuration file.

2: place ft_min_word_len=1 line after [mysqld] line in my.ini

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=1
```

3: restart your server

4: repair your table using below command

> repair table tablename;

5: now your search is working....

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're running into the minimum length limit, as stated in the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Comment: ya as I suspected :( So what's the solution?

Comment: I'm no MySQL guru - but I'd expect that this limit can be changed somewhere - check through server / database / table settings.

Comment: Yes Will you were right.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

But this will be a problem in a shared hosting environment where I will not have access to the config files. :( DANG!

Comment: Doesn't look good - time to change your States to the full names.  :)

Answer (score 1):

For future references. The answers above are related to `myisam` engine (not `innodb`).

So, to fix the minimum length of words for `innodb` you need [innodb_ft_min_token_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size) (default value: 3)

`my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_ft_min_token_size=2
```

Then rebuild the index ([source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-rebuild-innodb-indexes)):

```
alter table your_name drop index index_name;
alter table your_name add fulltext(field_name);
```

In order to check which engine you use execute the following query and see the `Engine` column:

```
show table status where `name` = 'table_name';
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested both MyISAM and InnoDB.

The *leading* '*' seems to be ignored.

Because of the *trailing* '*', `ft_min_word_len` or `innodb_min_token_size` is ignored.

If your dataset is mostly for businesses in "IL", the following rule may kick in:  "If more than 50% of the rows contain a word, that word is not indexed."

Also, don't forget about "stopwords".