# Searching multiple keywords in database mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

My search function explodes the string in multiple keywords after every empty space. It then runs a query where it will search for these keywords in the tags column.

However, because I'm using AND between the LIKES, it returns only the results where every keyword is in the tags column. If I use OR it will show every result with one or more of the keywords located in the tags column.

How can I get a sentence like: "How to cut an onion?" to find the results if the result will only have the keywords: cutting, onion.

My code:

```
$searchTerms = explode(' ', htmlspecialchars($_GET['tags'], ENT_QUOTES));
$searchTermBits = array();
foreach ($searchTerms as $term) {
    $term = trim($term);
    if (!empty($term)) {
        $searchTermBits[] = "tags LIKE '%$term%'";
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM results WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $searchTermBits)." ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Comment: So you want to match at least 2 keywords?

Comment: Think you are better of switching to fulltext search (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html). having so many likes (and joins) will be very bad for your performance/response times

Comment: Two or three or all, but right now it searches for "how" AND "to" AND ... and if the tags in the result don't include every keyword, no result will be shown. However if I use OR it will include every result where "cutting" is a tag.

Comment: You mean to get "cut" it's returning results with words that have similarity?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a fulltext search, but you should keep in mind performance issues as it becomes slower and slower the larger the database gets.

MATCH will exclude search words of 3 characters (i think) and less. This can be adjusted in your primary SQL file (my.cnf) in the root of your server. (more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381753/mysql-match-doesnt-work-with-two-characters))

Also remember to properly escape your search term. This example does not do that.

Example:

```
$sql = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp_search` 
        (FULLTEXT INDEX (tags)) 
        Engine=MyISAM 
        SELECT * FROM `results`";

// execute sql;

$sql =  "SELECT *,
        MATCH(tags) AGAINST ('".$term."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as `tags_relevance`
        FROM `tmp_search`
        WHERE MATCH(tags) AGAINST ('".$term."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
        ORDER BY tags_relevance DESC";

// get results from sql
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this SQL and make your PHP script output it:

```
SELECT * FROM results WHERE tags LIKE ('%cutting%') AND tags LIKE ('%onion%')
```