# Why can't I MATCH() AGAINST() one of the columns in my FULLTEXT index?

Tags: mysql, full-text-indexing

Here's the CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `EntityAddresses` (
  `EntityAddress_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Entity_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CreateDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `CreatedBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UpdateDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `UpdatedBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `StreetAddress` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `StreetAddress2` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `City` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `State` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `PostalCode` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Country` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`EntityAddress_ID`),
  KEY `Entity_ID` (`Entity_ID`),
  KEY `CreatedBy` (`CreatedBy`),
  KEY `UpdatedBy` (`UpdatedBy`),
  FULLTEXT INDEX `EntityAddresses_ibft_1` (`StreetAddress`,`StreetAddress2`,`City`,`State`,`PostalCode`,`Country`), 
  CONSTRAINT `EntityAddresses_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Entity_ID`) REFERENCES `Entities` (`Entity_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `EntityAddresses_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`CreatedBy`) REFERENCES `Users` (`User_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `EntityAddresses_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`UpdatedBy`) REFERENCES `Users` (`User_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here's an example record:

```
                       EntityAddress_ID: 5908
                              Entity_ID: 4514
                             CreateDate: 2015-05-25 13:59:43
                              CreatedBy: 2
                             UpdateDate: 2015-05-25 13:59:43
                              UpdatedBy: 2
                          StreetAddress: Testing 123
                         StreetAddress2: 
                                   City: Singapore
                                  State: 
                             PostalCode: 
                                Country: SG
```

Here's the query that should return the example record above:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `EntityAddresses`
WHERE
    MATCH (`StreetAddress` , `StreetAddress2` , `City` , `State` , `PostalCode` , `Country`) AGAINST ('+SG' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

When I try the same query with "Singapore" in place of "SG", it returns a result set including the example record above, but "SG" returns nothing. I have tried other countries and I'm getting the same result, 0 rows.

Comment: If 50% of your records contain the text you search for, then it will be ignored. Is this the case for you?

Comment: Also the default for minimum word length to be included in fulltext index is 3.

Comment: @Marki555 That would be the issue. Can you provide it as an answer with a reference to the documentation? I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @juergend that is not the case for this, but I was not aware of that. thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3381924/575376

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL fulltext engine has defined minimum word length to be included in the index. This is by default **3**, so that's why it won't find your text `SG`.

You can change the MySQL server variable `innodb_ft_min_token_size`. The change will be visible for newly created and re-created indexes only.

[MySQL manual for `innodb_ft_min_token_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size) says this:

> Minimum length of words that are stored in an InnoDB FULLTEXT index.
>   Increasing this value reduces the size of the index, thus speeding up
>   queries, by omitting common word that are unlikely to be significant
>   in a search context, such as the English words “a” and “to”. For
>   content using a CJK (Chinese, Japanese, Korean) character set, specify
>   a value of 1.