# Index to search in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

### Problem

TL;DR
My query is slow.

Im trying to find multiple `customer` by a given search-term "J". The fields im scanning are distributed among 2 tables `customer` and `company_customer`:

- `firstname` begins with
- `lastname` begins with
- `number` begins with (this is the specific customer-number for a company/custumer combination)

I'm having a hard time optimizing the database and query (running mysql-8).

I've tested this with 10 companies and 100k customers each. The search took **close to half a second** - there has to be a way to get this faster.

### The query

```
SELECT
    cc.number,
    c.firstname,
    c.lastname
FROM
    customer c
    JOIN company_customer cc
        ON cc.customer_id = c.id
WHERE
    cc.company_id = 1
    AND (
           c.lastname LIKE 'J%'
        OR c.firstname LIKE 'J%'
        OR cc.number LIKE 'J%'
    )
ORDER BY
    lastname,
    firstname
LIMIT 20;
```

### The schema (simplyfied)

- company (id, ...)
- customer (id, ...)
- company_customer (company_id, customer_id, number)

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/82KBeQ2yT3BFyAhpoyc6BA/2)

### What I've tried

- remove the actual search part to pinpoint the problem (every `like`) - still slow
- get a list of `customer.id` via subselect - even slower
- split the search - but when i search for `customer`s i only want to search for those associated with a specific `company_cusomer.company_id` - so i cant get around the join right?
- Find possible index by using `EXPLAIN`

### What I've found out

I think the problem is the index for `lastname, firstname` is not being used since the `JOIN` occupies the index usage - since only one may be used.

### The question

Is there a way to set an index to get the data faster?
Or a way to rewrite the sql to get the data faster?

### Edit

the explain (before with 1M rows in customers):

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys           | key     | key_len | ref                 | rows   | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cc    | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,IDX_co,IDX_cu   | PRIMARY | 4       | const               | 204966 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY | 4       | test.cc.customer_id |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

the explain (before 1M rows):

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-----------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys         | key     | key_len | ref             | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-----------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY               | IDX_lf  | 804     | NULL            |   20 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cc    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,IDX_co,IDX_cu | PRIMARY | 8       | const,test.c.id |    1 |   100.00 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-----------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Can you add the `EXPLAIN` output for the query? ... Simply add the word EXPLAIN before the `SELECT`.

Comment: @PaulT. I've added the explain. This is the explain with the 10*100k data. If you have a look at the linked fiddle you can see the explain aswell. (No temporary/filesort in the fiddle however)

Comment: First I would use a full text search instead of like.

Comment: If you create `IDX_lf` so that it indexes columns `id`, `lastname` and `firstname`, the index will be used instead of the primary key.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator doesnt the fulltext-search require min 3 or 4 chars?

Comment: @PaulT. I've noticed the explain changes as more data gets added, maybe there is a mysql-setting that need to be increased?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about `the explain changes`, if more rows are added, I would expect the number of rows to change, at least? Note that with the suggested index applied, the `rows` column dropped from almost 205,000 to 20, which should have helped the query's speed dramatically. Previously, the `Extra` column had `Using temporary; Using filesort`, but now has `Using index` which is better. So what is the time difference now, as you said 0.5 a sec before the index was applied?

Comment: @PaulT. the second explain is one i did while generating the data. So the "Using temporary/filesort" is the one currently getting applied. Ill tune some settings on the server, maybe it need more space to cache indexes or something. - I did not measure the time while generating - so i sadly dont have the querytime you asked for. Ill create a copy and trim the data.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-restrictions.html

Comment: @jmvcollaborator thanks, have a look here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381753/mysql-match-doesnt-work-with-two-characters) so its configurable. I'll apply this after the index problem is solved.

Comment: Explain will change based on the data and the arguments.  'J%' or 'S%' may eschew the indexed due to how common that leading character is, while `X%` or `Q%` might eagerly use some index.  I've seen as many as 6 distinctly different Explains for a single query.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` is tells you whether it is using an index; it does not suggest an index that you don't already have.

Comment: Indexes (in InnoDB) are cached in the buffer_pool along with the data.  Set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70% of _available_ RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OR`, especially since it touches more than one table, is especially hard to optimize.

These may help:

```
cc:  INDEX(company_id, number, customer_id)
c:  INDEX(lastname, firstname, id)
```

The best optimization (especially for huge tables) would be to switch to `UNION`:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
        ( SELECT ... with one of the LIKEs ...
              ORDER BY c.lastname, c.firstname LIMIT 20 )
        UNION DISTINCT
        ( SELECT ... with another of the LIKEs ...
              ORDER BY c.lastname, c.firstname LIMIT 20 )
        UNION DISTINCT
        ( SELECT ... with the other LIKE ...
              ORDER BY c.lastname, c.firstname LIMIT 20 )
         ) AS x
    ORDER BY lastname, firstname   -- again
    LIMIT 20      -- again
    ;
```

And more indexes (note reordering of columns:

```
cc:  INDEX(number, company_id, customer_id)
c:  INDEX(firstname, lastname, id)
```

(There may be a further optimization, but give this a try first.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this helped me understand the problem furthermore.
The root of the Problem seems to be that when i search for `number` which sits in `company_customer` with a short search-term many `company_customer` entries match, which have to be sortet by `fist-/lastname` before they get limited. - Your technique reduced the time to 70ms though - so THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: 70-350ms depending on how many `number` match. Maybe i just have to split the search in code. Since when i type in a number it only makes sense to look for it if its a certain length (min 3 for example) - A search for '1%' wouldnt give me the result I'm looking for anyways. If you want to see how i understood your technique (i hope i did this correctly :D): https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/82KBeQ2yT3BFyAhpoyc6BA/3

Comment: @SirPilan - If `cc.number` is numeric, then, by all means, write code in your app to first determine whether the user has entered digits or letters.  Then run one of two queries.  Each can be written much simpler; the results may be much faster.

Comment: Sadly its not :/

Comment: @SirPilan - What are some examples of `number`?

Comment: No pattern, already checked that  - anything you can think of. Sometimes names, sometimes dates (including dots) - but the vast majority are actually numbers. (99.6%)

Comment: When the user asks for a numeric match, test only cc.number.  At least _those_ cases will run faster.